# jQuery: setting checkbox values from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a script for setting checkboxes according to values stored in an array (part of a larger script for allowing the user to revert a form to its initial values). The code is basically this:

```
$("#myForm :checkbox[name='myName[]']").each(function(){
    if($.inArray($(this).val(),initValues)!=-1){
        $(this).prop("checked",true);
    } else {
        $(this).prop("checked",false);
    }
});
```

initValues contains the value attributes of the boxes that were initially checked.

The script checks the first element in `$("#myForm :checkbox[name='myName[]']")` but subsequent elements all appear to be unchecked. Firebug shows that the `checked` attribute is being changed but the box itself is unchecked.

I have tried verious permutations of `attr()` in place of `prop()` all with the same results, and the script behaves the same way in Firefox 11.0 and Chrome 18.0 on OS X.

Comment: Provide some HTML, please. It's possible that `.val()` isn't returning the values you expect.

Comment: `.prop()` is correct. Your code works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/DmVYa/). Are you using a recent version of jQuery?

Comment: I did consider that but as far as I can tell, it is, and the `$.inArray()` test is working as it should. The HTML is part of an enormous project so a bit complex to display here but I will try and work up a test case. Thanks

Comment: I am using jQuery v1.7.2

Comment: Your example works for me too, as does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/toppy/DmVYa/10/) which is closer to how the script is actually implemented. I'm totally stumped. There is a lot of other stuff going on e.g. the form is one of several forms on the page, they are enclosed in a jQuery UI Tabs etc. I can only guess there is a weird conflict somewhere. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var initValues = ['eee', 'mec', 'csc'];

            $('#btnResetCheckBox').click(function () {
                $('#myForm').find(':checkbox[name^="myName"]').each(function () {
                    $(this).prop("checked", ($.inArray($(this).val(), initValues) != -1));
                });

                //Or 

                //                $('#myForm').find(':checkbox[name^="myName"]').prop('checked', false);
                //                $.each(initValues, function (i, val) {
                //                    $('#myForm').find(':checkbox[name^="myName"][value="' + val + '"]').prop("checked", true);
                //                });
            });

            $('#btnResetCheckBox').trigger('click');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm" action="">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="myName[1]" value="eee" />eee<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="myName[2]" value="ece" />ese<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="myName[3]" value="it" />it<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="myName[4]" value="csc" />csc<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="myName[5]" value="mec" />mec<br />
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="btnResetCheckBox" value="Reset Check Box" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way. If you give each of your checkboxes the same class, you can actually just pass an array into .val for the class.

```
jQuery(".nameInput").val(initValues);
```

It's simple, elegant, and works

Comment: That's ace! works great thanks. Very tidy.

Answer (score 0):

html attributes can be messup if not set as string.

I suggest replacing:

```
$(this).prop("checked",true);
```

by

```
$(this).prop("checked","checked");
```

---

or

```
$(this).prop("checked",false);
```

by

```
$(this).prop("checked","");
```